# a story whose end

Tags: relative-pronouns

The speaker uses "whose end" rather than "the end of which", why? What rhetorical device does he apply? Since "who" refers usually to humans, I guess the device is personification like using "she" or referring to your beloved country. I am not sure.

> We have a place, all of us, in a long story - **a story** we continue, but **whose end we will not see**.

Source: George W. Bush's first inaugural address

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inanimate_whose has some background on it - the gist of it is that "whose" as a relative pronoun doesn't have a one-to-one inanimate equivalent (and requires longer phrases such as the one you've suggested), so some style guides accept it for inanimate objects as well.

Comment: No, it is not personification. _Whose_ has long been applied to inanimates. I suppose it is possible that there was originally personication, but I doubt even that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"whose" has long been used to refer to the property of things as well as people. Here's a dictionary definition. [my emphasis]

> **whose**
>
> used for showing that someone or something belongs to or is
> connected with the person or ***thing*** that you have just mentioned
>
> Help is needed for families whose homes were destroyed in the bombing.
>
> Haig led the British army, under whose command the Commonwealth forces also
> fought.
>
> They live in a house ***whose*** roof could collapse at any
> time.
>
> https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/whose